# Mysterious 404 routing error caused just by using 'x' prefix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to keep my URLs as short as possible, so I am testing routes without separators, like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Photo",
   url: "x{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Content", action = "Photo" }
);
```

For some reason the route above doesn't work, I am getting 404 errors:

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.

However when I change the **x** prefix for a different letter, say **g**, it's working fine.

There are no conflicting routes. What am I missing here, please?

**EDIT:**

I am seeing this problem again and I have observed that 404 is probably happening only when the `id` contains **x**, i.e. routes like `/xa1B2` or `/xZ9y8` work flawlessly, but `x12xG` fails. Any ideas, please?

Comment: It could be a bug, or something on your side. Debug your routes: http://attributerouting.net/#debugging

Comment: Is that supposed to be `url: "x/{id}",`?

Comment: I am not sure but it might be interpreted as a hex (unicode) char for example /xa1b2 in unicode char http://www.codetable.net/hex/a1b2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx):

> You can define more than one placeholder between delimiters, but they must be separated by a constant value. For example, {language}-{country}/{action} is a valid route pattern. However, {language}{country}/{action} is not a valid pattern, because there is no constant or delimiter between the placeholders. Therefore, routing cannot determine where to separate the value for the language placeholder from the value for the country placeholder.

As you already stated, the error happens when your id starts with an `x`. This is because there is no way for it to tell the difference between your id value and the constant you have chosen.

Some options that you can use to fix this:

1. Put a separator character between the constant and the placeholder that does not occur as the first character of any "id".
2. Choose a character for a constant that does not occur as the first character of any "id".
3. Change the "id" so it cannot start with `x`.
4. Add a duplicate route, one with a constraint to bypass when the "id" contains `x` and start the second route with another character.

The 4th option would look something like this:

```
// Ids that don't contain x will use this route
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Photo_X",
   url: "x{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Content", action = "Photo" },
   constraints: new { id = @"(?i)[^x]" }
);

// Ids that contain x will use this route instead
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Photo_Y",
   url: "y{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Content", action = "Photo" }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar issues before creating routes which don't have separators between constant values and parameters. While I can't explain exactly why this happens, I have to say for the amount of grief it's obviously causing you, why not just spend one extra character and put either a '/' or '-' back into the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Photo",
   url: "x-{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Content", action = "Photo" }
);
```

I suspect either will fix the problem for you, and really what's one extra character on a URL?

EDIT:

I've a good feeling I know why this happens but haven't been able to find any evidence to back it up. I suspect that when your URL contains another `x` like this `x12xG`, the routing engine can't work out whether `{id}` should be `12xG` or just `G`, so it considers the route ambiguous and ignores it. Since you don't have a suitable fallback route, you get the 404.

Per my comment, if you can use a route constraint to restrict the allowed values of `{id}` using a regular expression, you might be able to work around this. I think your best bet is if `{id}` is always a fixed length string then your constraint can enforce this and it might get you a match.

Comment: +1 for your suggestion Will, this would certainly work.. But still I would like to see if separator-less routing is a way to go (or at least understand what is the root cause of the behavior described)

Comment: You could try adding a route constraint if you can work out a regular expression that will satisfy the possible values of your id field? http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

Comment: Adding constraint surprisingly didn't help. I ended up routing all 4-character long URLs to my action. Anyway, thanks for your suggestions.